# Error in opening & repairing word through Powershell script

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, ms-word

I am using the following powershell script code to open and repair corrupted documents.

```
            $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
            $word.Visible = $true

            $word.documents.Open($Doc, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $true, $true)

            #Log opening the file
            Log-Write -LogPath "$Logpathfilename" -LineValue "$DocLeaf  - Opening File"
            RepairProgress "Repair Progress $count of $totcnt " "Input box contains current file path and name, select and paste into Save As Dialog box if neccessary. Select the checkbox on repair outcome."  "$Doc"  
            # "Repair Outcome: $global:Outcome "
            Log-Write -LogPath "$Logpathfilename" -LineValue "$DocLeaf  - Repair Outcome:   $global:Outcome"`
```

I have also tried giving the command like below:

```
$word.documents.Open($inputFile, $refFalse,  $true, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $true, $null, $null, $null)
```

> But the open command throws execption as "Exception calling "Open" with "13" argument(s): "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"
>   At \AD\MyND_GL\Profile\jgeo1.AD\Desktop\Training\DO1.ps1:550 char:17
>   +                 $word.documents.Open($Doc, $false, $false, $false, $false, $fals ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation"

Comment: [Documents.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx) takes 16 parameters.

Comment: If you're able to, enable Developer options and record a VBA macro opening and repairing a document.  Then script that.